# Getting SQLite syntax error in ICS(4.0.4) but works fine on other versions?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

The SQL is

```
INSERT INTO "quotes" VALUES(1,1,1,'This is a quote','This is a quote in german','By Me','jackson',1,1,1305587611,'0','Thriller');
```

I am using  db.execSQL to execute this line after reading it from a text file.

```
            InputStream is = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quotesinsert);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String readLine = null;
            db.execSQL(QUOTE_DB_CREATE);                    
            while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                db.execSQL(readLine); 
            }
```

This works every other version of Android but is crashing on an ICS(4.0.4)

```
01-14 02:07:46.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foo.quotesapp/com.foo.quotesapp.QuoteList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?INSERT": syntax error
```

I have tried both the SQL that creates the table and this insert in a standalone SQLite program and they work fine, what could be happening here?

Comment: Please show your code that generates this `INSERT` command.

Comment: INSERT command is not generated it is read as is from a text file and executed with db.execSQL(sqlcommand) see edit.

Comment: Log each Insert command before executing them and look at the one which generates this error message.  It's possible that you have some problem with the encoding if you have german characters in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file is encoded in UTF-8 and was created with a program that inserts a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning.

The Java/Android runtime does not remove this character when reading from the file; you have to do this yourself.
(This behaviour is deliberate; see [UTF-8 encoding does not recognize initial BOM](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058) and [UTF-8 decoder handling of byte-order mark has changed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6378911).)

Comment: Interesting so this changed for ICS only? Because it seems to work on all version before and after.

Comment: Anyway, I have decided to remove the file reading thing completely, now all the data is in a Java class as objects, I create ContentValues out of them and use the SQLiteDatabase.insert method to insert the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the sql statement is Single (space Before and space after the SQL statement)